# is GLTools a standard OpenGL library?

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d

i've been reading (openGL  superbible 5th Edition) for a while, in which iam really satisfied by it's contents, but somehow i got confused at a point where the book uses GLTools library extensively, which seems hard to me to comprehend, my question is:

1. is GLtools library a standard opengl library?? or it is specificly written for SuperBible book.
2. & if iam stuck on using this library anyway, any recommendations about reference regarding GLTools library?

Comment: How do you define "standard"? And why would you be stuck using the library anyway? The Superbible does *eventually* teach you how to do all that stuff manually. So just do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is GLtools library a standard opengl library??

OpenGL is not a library; although the original meaning of the L in GL was indeed library, I personally backronymed it to ***L***ayer.

From a technical point of view, OpenGL is "merely" a specification, i.e. a (lengthy) document describing the system, and what implementations must conform to. Then there are actual implementations (usually part of your GPU's driver).

Apart from what's written in the OpenGL spec, nothing else can be expectred from a OpenGL implementation.

*GLtools* is definitely not a part of OpenGL.

Comment: that was very informative, thanks for your help and effort...

Answer (score 3):

It is specifically written for the OpenGL super bible (I also have a copy and am currently reading it). I would suggest moving away from GLtools as soon as possible. GLtools is just a helper library there for convenience. You should start learning to use GLM and writing your own buffer objects. This will get you better prepared for further OpenGL 3.x-4.x ventures. It will also prepare your to handle your shaders better as well.

Comment: thank you for your help, i am really confused about it now this is a huge relief, i will consider your suggestion ..